# ETABS API with C++: Can I get a Model object from an edb file without opening ETabs?

Tags: c++, edb

I knew we have a way to get the Etabs model object by calling the function to open the Etabs application. However, in many cases, we need to import data from etabs file but don't want to open the Etabs application.
Is there any way to get the Model object from an edb file without opening ETabs application? Can anyone point me?

Comment: To clarify your question I suggest wording it like "ETABS API with C++: Can I get a Model object from an edb file without opening ETabs?"

Comment: Thank you so much, I will modify the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two way to get and set data to Etabs. first one is to read and write on e2k files and second way is to use "CSI API ETABS v1.chm" the file for using Etabs Interfa